# Issue triangulating a font glyph for a specific scenario

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to triangulate TTF glyphs for drawing in opengl. The below image shows an example glyph (Taken fron FontForge application). The X represent control points of a bezier spline, circular and square points represent points on the glyph but they can also be the start / end points of the bezier splines.

I have a triangulation process that can take all these points and render them in opengl, I'd like to render the bezier curves in a shader, I have something that does this and it works. They way I split things up is to take the control points, the start points and end points of the bezier spline and pass those to the bezier shader. For the curves that curve out side the shape I need to remove the control points from the triangulation routine (because I don't want to fill in these triangles completely, I leave that to the bezier shader). For the control points that curve in to the shape I keep them for the opposite reason to above.

[image: TTF Glyph Original]

For the example above I have shown some additional red lines showing what the new outline would look like with the outer control points removed. That can be seen below.

This shows an example of the issue I am having, I can no longer triangulate this because the red lines at the bottom cross outside the shape and then back in again.

Is there a better algorithm I can use to do this to avoid situations like this?

[image: TTF Glyph Post Curve Triangle Removal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points and control points define a spline curve. Your graphics hardware is usually not capable of handling splines directly, so you convert the spline into a polygon. You'll add enough points to the polygon so that the difference between spline and polygon is negligible. Control points are NOT part of the spline! So adding them to your straight line segments is a massive mistake. Don't do that, and your problem goes away.

I'd start with the points that are given to be on the curve, then figure out how many points you need to add between these points to keep the error low enough. You might want to add points just in the middle, so the same letter at a bigger size will contain all the points of a smaller size letter plus additional ones, and the curves will look the same.

For best quality, make sure that the area where the polygon is to the left of the spline and the area where it is to the right is about the same. That's because this could affect line thickness, and that is something very, very easy to spot by the naked eye.

Comment: I already have a working shader to render bezier splines, that is not my issue. I am also aware that the control points are not part of the spline, but I use the start, control, end points to form a triangle and in the shader I work out where to draw and where not to draw. I already have the line approximation model implemented but that is not what I want to do here. I want implement a smooth curve in the shader and fill the rest with triangles.